# Interface cannot simultaneously extend types anchor and button

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following interface for a React button (that can be an anchor or button):

```js
type ButtonTypes = HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLButtonElement;

interface ButtonProps<T extends ButtonTypes>
    extends React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<T>, React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<T> {
    className?: string;
    kind: 'default' | 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'tertiary';
    disabled?: boolean;
    icon?: React.ReactElement<React.HTMLProps<HTMLOrSVGElement>>;
    trailingIcon?: boolean;
    iconOnly?: boolean;
    fullWidth?: boolean;
    outline?: boolean;
    size?: 'small' | 'large';
    href?: string;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

But I'm getting the error that I can't extend both `React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<T>` and `React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<T>` due to named property 'type' of types are not identical...

However this is inspired by how Material Design have built their button: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react/blob/master/packages/button/index.tsx#L38

So not sure why I can't inherit from both but they (MDC) have been able to? Am I missing something (syntax or type package) to allow this behaviour?

Comment: They are extending `AnchorHTMLAttributes` not `HTMLAnchorElement`. Even though I don't know how `AnchorHTMLAttributes` looks, it probably not your case..

Comment: I'm extending `AnchorHTMLAttributes` as well...

Comment: Ao, sorry. I thought that you're talking about `ButtonTypes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this I had to overwrite the type property by adding:

`type?: 'submit' | 'reset' | 'button';` into my `ButtonProps` interface.

I also had to change how my buttons were built from:

```
if (href) {
    return (
        <a {...(props as React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>)} href={href}>{btnContent}</a>
    )
}

return (
    <button {...(props as React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>)}>{btnContent}</button>
);
```

to:

```
if (href) {
    return (
        <a {...(props as React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>)} href={href}>{btnContent}</a>
    )
}

return (
    <button {...(props as React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>)}>{btnContent}</button>
);
```